# Android: `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS` not limiting number of results

Tags: android

I am using Android's [`SpeechRecognizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) and want to limit the number of transcription results that Google returns.

From the documentation, [EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS) in the `RecognizerIntent` looks like what I want:

> Optional limit on the maximum number of results to return. If omitted the recognizer will choose how many results to return. Must be an integer.

However, adding this extra to the intent has no effect. The `Bundle` in `onResults` always has five transcriptions, regardless of what number I specify.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 2); //should limit to 2 results

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        recognizer.startListening(intent);
      }
    });
  }

  @Override public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    if (matches != null && !matches.isEmpty()) {
      Log.d("All matches", "number matches: " + matches.size()); //always 5
    }
  }
...

}
```

What is the correct way to limit the number of transcriptions that Google returns?

Comment: amazing that this has not been answered or commented on by anyone given that this android/google bug has been left in the APIs for so many years.